# Equals Operator with Listbox & Math not working properly

Tags: vb.net, math, listbox, equals

I'm finished with my homework my teacher asked for. The math isn't calculating out to what it should be. The math is working corectly for Handling Stress, Time management, and supervision skills. When I get to Negotiation, and How to interview. I am getting random numbers.
How to interview(395) + Dallas(110) = 505
But I am getting 725. I think it's doing 395 + (110x3).

```
Public Class frmMain
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim Workshops As New ArrayList()
    Workshops.Add(New Workshop("Handling Stress", "595"))
    Workshops.Add(New Workshop("Time Management", "695"))
    Workshops.Add(New Workshop("Supervision Skills", "995"))
    Workshops.Add(New Workshop("Negotiation", "1295"))
    Workshops.Add(New Workshop("How to Interview", "395"))
    lbWorkshop.DataSource = Workshops
    lbWorkshop.DisplayMember = "Workshop"
    lbWorkshop.ValueMember = "Price"
    lbWorkshop.ClearSelected()

    Dim Location As New ArrayList()
    Location.Add(New Workshop("Austin", "95"))
    Location.Add(New Workshop("Chicago", "125"))
    Location.Add(New Workshop("Dallas", "110"))
    Location.Add(New Workshop("Orlando", "100"))
    Location.Add(New Workshop("Phoenix", "92"))
    Location.Add(New Workshop("Raleigh", "90"))
    lbLocation.DataSource = Location
    lbLocation.DisplayMember = "Workshop"
    lbLocation.ValueMember = "Price"
    lbLocation.ClearSelected()

End Sub

Private Sub lblAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblAdd.Click


    Dim description As String
    Dim value As Integer

    If (lbWorkshop.SelectedIndex > -1) Then
        If (lbLocation.SelectedIndex > -1) Then
            lblStatus1.Text = String.Empty
            If (lbWorkshop.SelectedItem.Equals("How to Interview")) Then
                value = lbWorkshop.SelectedValue + lbLocation.SelectedValue
            ElseIf (lbWorkshop.SelectedItem.Equals("Negotiation")) Then
                value = lbWorkshop.SelectedValue + (lbLocation.SelectedValue * 5)
            Else
                value = lbWorkshop.SelectedValue + (lbLocation.SelectedValue * 3)
            End If
            description = value.ToString

            lbTotal.Items.Add(description)
            lbTotal.ValueMember = value

            Dim total As Integer
            For Each Str As String In lbTotal.Items
                total = total + CInt(Str)
            Next
            lblTotal.Text = FormatCurrency(total.ToString)
        Else
            lblStatus1.Text = "Please Select a Location"
        End If
    Else
        lblStatus1.Text = "Please Select a Workshop"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think that `lbWorkshop.SelectedItem.Equals(<string>)` works exactly as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

it's doing what you asked, as far as I can tell.  Is this your intention?

```
       Else  'Supervision Skills, Negotiation, How to Interview
            value = lbWorkshop.SelectedValue + (lbLocation.SelectedValue * 3)
```

Comment: No. 
    If its equal to how to inverview, than just add the two.
    ElseIf its equal to negotiaton, 1 + (1 *5).
    Else 'Handling Stress, Time management, and supervision skills.
            1+(1*3)

Comment: so you need to code that?  you have code for the first two workshops, and then an else clause, which the other 3 workshops fall into.  Try stepping through the code, it will help you see what's going on.